# Finding the Mean and Variance of this distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

Given the following:

$Y|\Lambda=\mathrm{Poisson(\Lambda)}$ and $\Lambda=\mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$

Find the distribution, mean and variance of $Y$.

After a lot of work, I was able to find the distribution of $Y$ which is:

$f_Y(y)={{\Gamma(y+\alpha)e^{(-y/\beta)}}\over{y!\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}}$

Now using this distribution, I wanted to find the mean and variance. I tried integrating the above results but I couldn't find a closed form for the product $\Pi_{i=1}^n{(y+\alpha-i)}$ and from their the integration breaks down.

I would appreciate if someone could provide me a way to calculate the mean and varaiance of Y. Thanks

Comment: $Y$ should have a negative-binomial distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture), from which the moments follow.

Comment: Yes the question tells us to show that it is a negative binomial distribution but could you please show me how you came to this conclusion through the distribution of Y? As my distribution doesn't consist of probability but the exp function

Comment: Did you see the derivation on the wiki page? You made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Ah yes. I see my mistake. Thank you very much

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly helpful when you're mixing fractions and exponents, which tend to become hard to read the way you typeset them.

Comment: If you solved the problem, you can post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by setting $\beta = (p/(1-p))$. I then followed the derivation of the Negative Binomial distribution as shown in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture). Since I wanted an answer in terms of $\beta$, I simply solved the above expression for $p$ and replaced $\beta$ with that expression, giving me Y~NB($\alpha$, $\beta/(1+\beta)$). From there the mean and variance can easily be found.